# Config file and SqlConnection initializing

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I have application (let`s call it **test.exe**) with following code in Window_Loaded:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
}
```

Nothing more and nothing less. Application works with no problems.
Now if I copy an empty config file (**test.config**) to the same directory, application crashes.

I did not add config file to the application project, it is just empty xml file manually copied to the same directory and renamed to .config (this file contains only xml declaration and will be used later).

I am able to catch exception about missing root with try-catch, but problem is that applications crashes after few second anyway.

Why is SqlConnection reading this config file? And why it crashes my application even after catching exception?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove the code line with the SqlConnection?

Comment: Yes. If I remove SqlConnection line it wont crash. Same goes if I remove/rename test.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your configuration file is called `test.exe.config`.

I would imagine that the application crashes when it first attempts to read its configuration file.  In your case, this is when you instantiate a `SqlConnection` instance, but there are lots of other ways it could happen.

Add a `<configuration>` element to your configuration file.

**EDIT**

Reproduced this behaviour and examined the stack trace.  The `DbConnectionPoolCounters` is accessing a `System.Diagnostics.TraceSwitch`, which needs to read configuration information from the configuration file.

You should add a `test.exe.config` file with a `<configuration>` element.  The configuration system will then use this file and ignore your empty `test.config` file.

Comment: Nope. File is called test.config (without .exe). And this config file does not belong to this application. It`s not added to solution. It`s just config file for other purposes located in same directory.

Comment: @majk86 - post the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I`m curious why it reads config file that does not belong to this app? Just bcs it`s called test.config? Is there way to turn off reading config file if this config file is not added to the solution?? Anyway marking as accepted answer.

Comment: "Is there way to turn off reading config file if this config file is not added to the solution?" - at runtime the configuration system doesn't care whether or not a file it finds was in a Visual Studio solution or not: it's looking for a file by name - presumably it looks first for appname.exe.config, then falls back to appname.config.

Comment: Well I can imagine something like IsConfigSet.. and search for config if it`s true. Since files like Settings.config can be pretty common.. and apps like our Settings.exe ..and here goes crash. Thanks for your time Joe

Answer (score 0):

try to use parameterized constructor of sqlconnection(). pass your connection string for safer side. your application will not depend on

Comment: Crashes anyway. new SqlConnection("Server='server';User='user';Password='password';")

Comment: How so?? Works like charm.